# Iterating over vector of custom object with two conditions

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Using C++11, I'd like to iterate over a vector and return a type that indicates that the index was not found.

I am use to the traditional `for(;;)` loop and specifying the index manually, as my code shows below.

```
inline std::size_t ItemList::FindItem(Items& Item)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ItemVector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ItemVector[i]->GetId() == Item.GetId() && !ItemVector[i]->GetName().compare(Item.GetName()))
        {
            return i + 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm also having to increment the index +1 in order to return a value of 0 (to accommodate unsigned size_t) to indicate the calling method that the index was not found (I understand this is asinine). I am assuming it would be more suitable to return something more like `std::end()`?

Would using a C++11 iterator approach be more efficient? The vector will populate to a large number and the find needs to be quick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and work with iterators:

```
auto it = std::find_if(ItemVector.begin(), ItemVector.end(), 
    [&Item](Items *value) {
        return value->GetId() == Item.GetId() && !value->GetName().compare(Item.GetName());
    }
);
```

Then you can simply test if `it != ItemVector.end()` to know if you found something.

There will likely be no (or very small) difference between this and your version in term of speed, but it is a cleaner way to check if something was found or not.

Comment: Because the original question passes `Item` by reference, I assume it's a large type. You might want to capture by reference with `[&Item]`.

Comment: This will return `end()` if the condition is not met, right?

Comment: @user0000001 Yes, this will return `end()` if no element matching the condition has been found.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, it looks like it is returning a boolean if it is found? What adjustments do I need to make to return an index (or distance) of the vector?

Comment: @user0000001 It returns an iterator to the found element, not a boolean, or `end()` if no element was found. If you want an index, you can simply substract `ItemVector.begin()`, e.g. `size_t idx = it - ItemVector.begin();`. You will get `ItemVector.size()` if no element was found.

Comment: @user0000001 `it` is an iterator, in a way it's a pointer to the element in question. So you can either dereference it directly to inspect the element, as in `*it` or use `distance` to find the index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an iterator would be the way to do this, you're actually writing your own version of [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) You could instead do:

```
find_if(cbegin(ItemVector), cend(ItemVector), [&](const auto& i){ return i.GetId() == Item.GetId() && i.GetName() != Item.GetName(); })
```

You can test whether the result of this function was found by testing for equality with `cend(ItemVector)`.

Additionally if you need to find the index of the item you can pass this result after `cbegin(ItemVector)` to: [`distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Dg3MxT)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for double search condition that Lambda has multiple parameters in find_if

```
bool check_second_loop(FullFrame *image_track, guint64 object_id, bool *deletion)
{
    auto itr= std::find_if(image_track->track_ids.begin(), 
                           image_track->track_ids.end(),
                           [object_id](const guint64& a)
    {
        return a == object_id;
    });

    if (itr != image_track->track_ids.end())
    {
        image_track->track_ids.erase(itr);
        if(image_track->track_ids.size()==0)
        {
            *deletion = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}


bool check_first_loop(guint64 object_id, gint source_id)
{
    bool deletion = false;
    auto it = find_if(full_frame_list.begin(), full_frame_list.end(),
                      [object_id, &deletion, source_id](FullFrame &x)
    {
            return check_second_loop(&x, object_id, &deletion) 
                && x.camera_number == source_id;
});

    if (it != full_frame_list.end())
    {
        // Found
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```